# Very Large and Very Sparse Non Negative Matrix factorization

Tags: python, bigdata, sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization, nmf

I have a very large and also sparse matrix (531K x 315K), the number of total cells is ~167 Billion. The non-zero values are only 1s. Total number of non-zero values are around 45K. Is there an efficient NMF package to solve my problem? I know there are couple of packages for that and they are working well only for small size of data matrix. Any idea helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which lib did you try? What's your model? And how many components you are looking for?

Comment: I tried scikit-learn lib and it failed. Also, tried https://nipunbatra.github.io/blog/2017/nnmf-tensorflow.html and it also failed due to the out of memory issue. The latent dimension is 50.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.NMF.html#sklearn.decomposition.NMF) will handle this **easily**!

#### Code:

```
from time import perf_counter as pc
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF

""" Create sparse data """
nnz_i, nnz_j, nnz_val = np.random.choice(531000, size=45000), \
                        np.random.choice(315000, size=45000), \
                        np.random.random(size=45000)
X =  sps.csr_matrix((nnz_val, (nnz_i, nnz_j)), shape=(531000, 315000))
print('X-shape: ', X.shape, ' X nnzs: ', X.nnz)
print('type(X): ', type(X))
# <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'> #                          !!!!!!!!!!

""" NMF """
model = NMF(n_components=50, init='random', random_state=0, verbose=True)

start_time = pc()
W = model.fit_transform(X)
end_time = pc()

print('Used (secs): ', end_time - start_time)
print(model.reconstruction_err_)
print(model.n_iter_)
```

#### Output:

```
X-shape:  (531000, 315000)  X nnzs:  45000
type(X):  <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
violation: 1.0
violation: 0.2318929397542804
violation: 0.11045394409727402
violation: 0.08104138988253409
...
violation: 9.659665625799714e-05
Converged at iteration 71
Used (secs):  247.94092973091756
122.27109041
70
```

#### Remarks:

- Make sure you use sparse-matrices as input or you can't exploit sparsity
- I'm using version *0.19.1*, so the *multiplicative-update* solver is used (>= 0.19)

  - But the older CD-based solver should handle this too!
- The above is using **< 800 MB of memory**

#### Additional Constraints

As mentioned in the comments, OP wants to add additional constraints, while still not specifying these formally.

This will need a whole new implementation of some optimization-procedure including some theory-footwork (depending on the constraints).

As an alternative, this can be solved by general-purpose Convex-Programming solvers. E.g. formulated by cvxpy and solved by SCS. Of course the alternating-minimization procedure needs to be done too (as the joint-problem is non-convex) and it will scale worse than this specialized sklearn-implementation. But it might work for OPs data.

Comment: thanks for the example but also I need to penalize some of the cells to be zero. Sklearn doesn't allow me to modify the cost function.

Comment: @mgokhanbakal And where was that specified in your question? Why did you try and mention sklearn then when i asked? There is no detailed/formal model in your question! And if so, you probably have to implement it yourself (the whole learning-procedure).

Comment: What ways are there to plot a three-dimension solution in an 3D axis? Thanks.

Comment: @Emmanuel plotly is a good place to start. https://plotly.com/python/pca-visualization/