# Fast NMF in R on sparse matrices

Tags: r, nmf

I'm looking for a fast NMF implementation for sparse matrices in R.

The R `NMF` package consists of a number of algorithms, none of which impress in terms of computational time.

`NNLM::nnmf()` seems state of the art in R at the moment, specifically the `method = "scd"` and `loss = "mse"`, implemented as alternating least squares solved by sequential coordinate descent. However, this method is quite slow on very large, very sparse matrices.

The `rsparse::WRMF` function is extremely fast, but that's due to the fact that only positive values in `A` are used for row-wise computation of `W` and `H`.

Is there any reasonable implementation for solving NMF on a sparse matrix?

Is there an equivalent to `scikit-learn` in R? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47535872/very-large-and-very-sparse-non-negative-matrix-factorization)

There are various worker functions, such as `fnnls`, `tsnnls` in R, none of which surpass `nnls::nnls` (written in Fortran). I have been unable to code any of these functions into a faster NMF framework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forgot I even posted this question, but one year later...

I wrote a very fast implementation of NMF in RcppEigen, see the `RcppML` R package on CRAN.

```
install.packages("RcppML")

# for the development version
devtools::install_github("zdebruine/RcppML")

?RcppML::nmf
```

It's at least an order of magnitude faster than `NNLM::nnmf` and for comparison, `RcppML::nmf` rivals the runtime of `irlba::irlba` SVD (although it's an altogether different algorithm).

I've successfully applied my implementation to 1.3 million single-cells containing 26000 genes in a 96% sparse matrix for rank-100 factorization in 1 minute. I think that's very reasonable.

Comment: very nice - works great!

Comment: must faster than NMF package on cran. in my machine it even caused a CPU power problem, and let the machine restarted. Be sure to limit the thread number used if anyone encountered the same.